# "Temporary object" warning - is it me or the compiler?

Tags: c++, warnings, c++builder

The following snippet gives the warning:

```
[C++ Warning] foo.cpp(70): W8030 Temporary used for parameter '_Val' in call to 'std::vector<Base *,std::allocator<Base *> >::push_back(Base * const &)'
```

.. on the indicated line.

```
class Base
{
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
 Derived()   // << warning disappears if constructor is removed!
 {
 };
};

std::vector<Base*> list1;
list1.push_back(new Base);
list1.push_back(new Derived);  // << Warning on this line!
```

Compiler is Codegear C++Builder 2007.

Oddly, if the constructor for Derived is deleted, the warning goes away...
Is it me or the compiler?

EDIT: The only way I've found to remove the warning is to something similar to this:

```
Derived * d;
list1.push_back(d = new Derived);  // << No warning now...
```

Comment: No warning on this code with gcc.

Comment: That's probably not *all* the code.   Do Base and Derived have constructors (non-compiler generated ones)?

Comment: @MadKeithV - give or take a #include <vector>, that is ALL the code. I started with a much more complex case and cut it down to the bare bones that shows the problem above.

Comment: Your problem are with the compiler. BCC32 have many issues, I guess this is another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple try:

```
list1.push_back(new Derived());
```

I am afraid there is something about POD (with trivial constructors) vs non-POD going on here.

**EDIT**:

Given that the code compiles fine with gcc.3.4.2 (--pedantic) I would say it's a compiler quirk. I am leaning toward `MarkB` explanation, ie the compiler creating a temporary even though I don't understand why it would be required and then complaining when assigning it to the `const&`... but I'm still perplex.

Comment: It's annoying that I don't have the compiler handy to experiment with it :/ It's really bizarre that the same warning is not generated for `Base`: or perhaps it's because `Base` does not have a user defined constructor ?

Comment: Base did have a user-defined constructor, but I trimmed it out as it made no difference to the problem. ie, using 'new Base' never gave a warning...

Comment: It does appear to be a compiler bug.

There's an open QC report on this issue, "Incorrect warning W8030." with almost identical code snippet.

http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=59272

Answer (score 2):

In a "pass by reference" call, if the argument type does not match the "formal parameter", then the compiler will try to convert the argument to the correct type. The argument will be considered as a 'value parameter' if the conversion is successful. The compiler generates the warning "Temporary used for ..." in this case.

Comment: Worked for me. int used in unsigned parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Since `list1` is a vector of `Base*`, the `push_back` function in the list is going to expect a parameter of type `Base* const&`, while your new is providing `Derived*`. In order to pass by reference (as needed in `push_back`) the compiler needs an actual object of the reference type, in this case `Base*`. There is an available implicit conversion from `Derived*` to `Base*` that the compiler uses to create a temporary object of type `Base*` to pass into `push_back`, and the compiler is warning you that it's creating this temporary.

The reason it works when you assign it to a variable is that there's no longer an implicit temporary needed: It can implicitly convert the named variable to `Base*` implicitly and pass that reference in.

I think you can silence this warning by telling push_back to treat the pointer as a `Base*`:

`list1.push_back(static_cast<Base*>(new Derived));`

Comment: Hmm. The cast doesn't change things, but I see what you're saying. I'm still not sure of the difference between the two implicit conversions, though.

Comment: OK, so why does the presence of the Derived() constructor matter...?

Comment: I was wondering about that but it doesn't make sense to me. If `Derived*` is implicitly convertible to `Base*` (as is the case) then why would a `Base*` and a `Derived*` be treated differently ? I don't see the need to create a temporary from `Derived*` to `Base* const&` (btw check the `const` position in your answer), and `const&` can be bounded to temporaries anyway... this is bugging me :/